# Fedora 30 Workstation breaking wifi router

Tags: fedora, wifi, gnome

I've confirmed that when turning on the wifi on a Fedora 30 Workstation and connecting to a local network router, the router breaks and starts behaving in a strange way. The router starts to drop the connection and come back up every few seconds, this affects all devices connected to it.

Connecting to the wifi router directly via ethernet cable also breaks it but not as frequently and not for a long time, its almost unnoticeable.

I've earlier ran Windows and Ubuntu on the same device that I installed Fedora on, so I am certain it's not a network card issue.

Things I tried:

- Disabling PMF
- Forgeting the wifi connection and reconnecting.
- Enabling/disabling NAT-PMP, IGMP snooping, 5G, firewalld, one at a time.

Hardware:

- Network controller is Intel Wireless-AC 9560.
- Ethernet controller is Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller.
- Router is Apple AirportExtreme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a known DDoS virus, as described here:

https://superuser.com/questions/863997/ddos-virus-infection-as-a-unix-service-on-a-debian-8-vm-webserver

Comment: Hi! I'm not convinced this does anything, because iwlwifi will be loaded already.  I don't think `modprobe` actually changes options if the module is already loaded.  Even if you unload iwlwifi first, this change will almost certainly not last. I would suggest creating a file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`, with the line `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 power_save=0`, and then rebooting.